# The labels won't show on my MaterialDesign tabs

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, angular-material

I've implemented angular material design tabs but the labels won't show up...the content will but not the labels.

I'm following the examples in the tutorials to no avail.  It seems like it would be straight forward but only the content is appearing and not the labels.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {ClipboardModule} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTabsModule, MatTab} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
        A11yModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    OverlayModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

I think imported this module into the page module I want to use the following code:

```html
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight>
  <mat-tab label="Short tab">
    <div class="example-small-box mat-elevation-z4">
      Small content
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Long tab">
    <div class="example-large-box mat-elevation-z4">
      Large content
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

This is what it looks like
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 9.1.12
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.12
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.12
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/fire                     5.4.2
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.12
@schematics/angular               9.1.12
@schematics/update                0.901.12
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Comment: You might be missing a theme file - do you import any material stylesheets? See here: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Comment: I think the problem is the text is white but I don't know how to manually change it in the hTML

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the test was white on a white background by default.  I changed the background and the text appeared.